# How to create UML Diagrams in Pycharm Community Edition?

Tags: pycharm, uml

Is it that one can you only create class diagrams in Pycharm Professional Edition?
I have Pycharm Community Edition 2019.2 and I have installed the `PlantUML plugin` and `Graphviz`, also set the environment variables as required but still I cant create the Class diagram.

Comment: Did you find a way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Based on searching online, I think the specific answer to your question is yes, you can only use the integrated UML plugins for Professional Edition. To do it for Community Edition, as Dinko said you would have to use the 3rd party plugin PlantUML.

Comment: Hi. I installed the 3rd party plugin PlantUML. I restart the PyCharm but i still do not have the option "Diagram" when I click in a python script.

Comment: Yeah, the question and my answer are little out of sync. The question states "How to create UML diagrams in Pycharm Community Edition?" and I provided answer how to create it with PyCharm Pro and PyCharm community. However, with PlantUML you can create UML diagrams but only using PlantUML syntax. UMLs are shown in PyCharm, it's only when you edit your Python Class, you must edit also PlantUML file. Unfortunately, there is no option to generate diagram using PlantUML as in PyCharm Pro.

Comment: did you try this plugin 
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7017-plantuml-integration

Answer (score 1):

[Generating UMLs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/viewing-diagram.html) from class in PyCharm is included by default. Maybe you have disabled them. Go to `File -> Settings -> Plugins` and search UML. There should be `Python UML` diagrams and `UML` which should have *bundled* keyword written below.

You can right click on class and and choose `Diagrams` to generate it.

For example, this class:

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
```

is represented as this:

[image: Example diagram]

---

For `PlantUML` plugin, you don't have to install anything except the plugin itself. When you install it, you can create new `PlantUML` file and select default diagram to be generated.

Comment: Nothing like Python UML plugin is bundled with the community edition of PyCharm

Comment: You have to install PlantUML plugin to be able to create UML diagrams.

Comment: Yes I get it but the first part of your answer deals only with the Professional Edition of PyCharm.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pyreverse from pylint for Pycharm Community Edition.

```
pip install pylint
pyreverse -o puml <src path>
```

Answer (score -1):

def search_by_description():
description = input("Enter the item description to search: ")

```
inventory = []
with open("inventory.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        data = line.strip().split("\t")
        inventory.append(data)

found = False
for item in inventory:
    if description.lower() in item[1].lower():
        found = True
        print("Item details:")
        print(f"Item Code: {item[0]}")
        print(f"Description: {item[1]}")
        print(f"Category: {item[2]}")
        print(f"Unit: {item[3]}")
        print(f"Price: {item[4]}")
        print(f"Quantity: {item[5]}")
        print(f"Minimum Threshold: {item[6]}")
        print()

if not found:
    print("No items found with the given description.")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).